# Akka Scheduling in Heroku with Play 2 Framework

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I can't get Akka schedule method to work properly in Heroku. It works fine locally and prints out "Heartbeat" to the log.

Here is  the file in question: https://github.com/magnusart/actor-test/blob/master/app/Global.scala and snippet below.

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.debug("Starting application")
    Akka.system(app).scheduler.schedule(2 seconds, 10 seconds) {
      Logger.debug("Heartbeat")
    }
  }
```

The full application is here (isolated for this purpose, also on actor-test.herokuapp.com).
https://github.com/magnusart/actor-test

What does happen after startup is that I see `Starting application` in the logs and then I don't see anything further after that:

```
2012-05-26T16:29:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=43943 -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
2012-05-26T16:29:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 3
2012-05-26T16:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [debug] application - Starting application
2012-05-26T16:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
2012-05-26T16:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Application started (Prod)
2012-05-26T16:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 43943...
```

So the scheduled actor doesn't actually seem to start (which it of course does locally). I'm on Heroku Cedar. I grateful for any hints as to why this isn't working, what am I missing?

BR Magnus Andersson

---

**Update**
From what I've found, this seems to be a bug in Play 2 (I'm running version 2.0.1) and not be related to Heroku. I have updated a Play 2 Lighthouse ticket with relevant information. The ticket can be found here: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/448-play-dist-ignores-loggerxml#ticket-448-5

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  You mean it's not actually doing the heartbeat at all?  This could be due to [dyno idling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-idling) if you are only running on 1 dyno.

Comment: I don't know if debug messages are printed on Heroku, since it is supposed to run the app in "production" mode.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the incomplete information. I have updated my text in the original question now. That include answers to both James, and nico_ekito's questions. I did look at the process with heroku ps and the process hadn't idled out yet (that comes an hour later in the log). Please add a comment if further clarifications are needed.

Comment: Actually, nico_ekito might be on to something, that was a good hint. I tried with play stage on my local machine and I don't get any print outs there neither. So there is definitely something going on with play stage that I don't understand. I will investigate a bit more post back here.

Comment: It seems like it was the logging. When I put the actor logging to error it actually prints out the "Heardbeat" in the logs. I found this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/cAvr2vRtyI0, that seems to talk about the same problem. According to that thread, Play resets the logging during startup. That would explain why I see debug log messages from startup method but not after that. Thank you for your help. Nico_ekito: if you post an answer outlining that I'll accept it, as you hinted what the problem was.

Comment: You can also start in Prod mode with `play start`.

Comment: James: thanks. I tried running play start (locally) and it seems to be the same behavior as play stage. This seems to potentially be a bug: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/448-play-dist-ignores-loggerxml#ticket-448-5 I have tried to replicate the information I've found there. Maybe that can get some attention for it. In the end, this seems to have nothing to do with Heroku.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to come from your logger setting, because in your Heartbeat you print a message with the "debug" level.
AFAIK, Heroku runs your Play app in "production" mode (= "play start"), ie the log level is set to "info" so the debug messages are never printed on Heroku.